# Python SQLite Вывод данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть метод `channels` который должен возвращать все записи из БД

```
import sqlite3

class Database:

    def __init__(self, database):
        """Подключаемся к БД и сохраняем курсор соединения"""
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def channels(self):
        with self.connection:
            for value in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall():
                return f"ID: {value[0]}\nTitle: {value[1]}\nURL: {value[2]}"
```

Но он возвращает лишь первое поле. Как мне вернуть все поля из таблицы `channels`

Comment: Попробуйте без `with self.connection:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Заполните в списке:

   ```
       def channels(self):
           items = []
           for value in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall():
               items.append(f"ID: {value[0]}\nTitle: {value[1]}\nURL: {value[2]}") 
           return items
   ```

   В одну строку:

   ```
       def channels(self):
           return [
               f"ID: {value[0]}\nTitle: {value[1]}\nURL: {value[2]}"
               for value in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall()
           ]
   ```
2. Верните как генератор:

   ```
       def channels(self):
           for value in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall():
               yield f"ID: {value[0]}\nTitle: {value[1]}\nURL: {value[2]}"
   ```

   В одну строку:

   ```
       def channels(self):
           yield from (
               f"ID: {value[0]}\nTitle: {value[1]}\nURL: {value[2]}"
               for value in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall()
           )
   ```

Убрал `with`, т.к. там нет запросов, меняющих таблицы в базе данных

---

Кст, в текущей конструкции имеет смысл `value` указать возвращаемые значения, для повышения читаемости кода:

```
for id_, title, url in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall():
    f"ID: {id_}\nTitle: {title}\nURL: {url}"
```

Это если у вас в таблице `channels` 3 поля, если больше, тогда укажите их явно в выборке: `SELECT id, title, url FROM channels`, либо при распаковке использовать `*args`:

```
for id_, title, url, *_ in self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `channels`").fetchall():
```

Comment: Спасибо, добавил джойн и всё красиво, ещё раз спасибо

Comment: выбрал вариант со списком)

Comment: @KLEYZYツ, пожалуйста :)